# Selecting previous element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hey guys, this is simple but I can't make it workn... blah!

I have a UL with many LI. Inside of each LI I have a  and two :

```
<ul>    
  <li><span>Qualification</span> - <a class="editItem" href="get/14">edit</a> | <a class="deleteItem" href="delete/14">delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click the delete anchor, I would like to hide the LI. How can I select the LI?

I tried something like this:

```
$(".deleteItem").click(function(e) {
     $(this).parent().find("li").hide();
     // or
     $(this).prev().prev().prev().hide();

});
```

But it doesn't work at all. :( What am I doing wrong? Thanks..

Comment: Thanks everybody! For some reason, using $(this) inside my ajax function wasn't working. But all the answers above are right. Thank you again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the LI:

```
$(".deleteItem").click(function(e) {
  $(this).closest("li").hide();
});
```

`.prev()` refers to siblings, in this case `<li>` is a parent to the link, `.closest()` gets the nearest parent matching the selector.

Answer (score 3):

The li is the parent of the anchor you're clicking, so you could do this:

```
$(".deleteItem").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $(this).parent().hide();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".deleteItem").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('li').hide();
});
```

Try that.

Answer (score 1):

should be simply:

$(this).parent().hide();

the LI is the parent of the A element. Others are siblings.
Prev is used to find the previous sibling, so it wont give you the parent.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your need to fire off a request to delete the record itself from the database too. So rather than focusing on *just* hiding the `li`, you shouldn't neglect your link's original purpose:

```
$(".deleteItem").click(function(e){
  // prevent page-change
  e.preventDefault();
  // ask server to delete this record
  $.post($(this).attr("href"), function(result){
    // remove this record upon server-response
    $(e.target).closest("li").slideUp().remove();
  });
});
```